# Is it possible to extract a part of the string by using the delimiter in Hive Script SQL?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have assigned a problem to group the problem that occurred to each id user by category. The category column is recorded in the form of "MainProblem@Detail1@Detail2". I would like to know if I can use the function substring_index() in hive script sql to extract the main problem and the detail2 at the end by the following code:

```
select 
substring_index(category_out_line, "@",1) as MainProblem,
substring_index(category_out_line, "@",-1) as Detail2 `
from TableA;
```

Comment: Have you actually tried your code?

Comment: I'm voting to close a not reproducible, because you have a question with valid SQL code and you are simply asking if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring_index like in your question to extract first and last element, but if you need extract all of them, or second, third, etc, split is better:

```
split("MainProblem@Detail1@Detail2",'@')[0] --returns MainProblem
split("MainProblem@Detail1@Detail2",'@')[1] --returns Detail1
split("MainProblem@Detail1@Detail2",'@')[2] --returns Detail2
```